# Copying one table to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have two gridviews one is connected to one table and the the other is connected to other table both in the same database

table1
table2

gridview1
gridview2

when a record in gridview1 is selected using the gridview select tool then by clicking a button it will move the record to table2 and now shown on gridview 2
iv'e tried

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow r = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string strQuery = "insert into table values('" + r.Cells[0] + "','" + r.Cells[1] + "')";
}
```

but i need it connected to button1   and  i tried others

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("MenuName");
    dt.Columns.Add("MenuID");

    foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in gridview1.Rows) ////////////// Add new Data from GridMenuList TO Datatable DT
        {
            if (((CheckBox)grdRow.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked)
            {
                DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();

                Label lblMenuName = (Label)grdRow.FindControl("lblMenuName");

                HiddenField hdnID = (HiddenField)grdRow.FindControl("hdnID");

                drow["MenuName"] = lblMenuName.Text;               
                drow["MenuID"] = hdnID.Value;

                dt.Rows.Add(drow);
            }
        }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gridview2.DataSource = dt;
        gridview2.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gridview2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        //e.Row.Cells[0].Text = dr["MenuName"].ToString();
        Label lblMenuName = e.Row.FindControl("lblMenuName") as Label;
        lblMenuName.Text = dr["MenuName"].ToString();

        HiddenField hdnID = e.Row.FindControl("hdnID") as HiddenField;
        hdnID.Value = dr["MenuID"].ToString();
     }
}
```

can't seem to get it to work

following user3607430 advice i tryed

```
protected void buttonMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    SqlCommand move = new SqlCommand("Command String", cn);
    cn.Open();
    move.CommandText = "INSERT into queue values  ('" + row.Cells[1].Text + "')";
    cn.Close();
}
```

but does not work

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use

`GridViewRow row = gridview1.SelectedRow;`

rather than running a loop to find the selected row. This will give you the row you want to add. Your grids are already connected to tables, so you are trying to attempt to bind it with DataTable variable, that means it will be disconnected from your table in the database. So once you have selected the row, you should get the data, add it to the table 2 and then call a refresh on `gridview2`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow newRow = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        newRow.Cells[i].Value = row.Cells[i].Value;
    }
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```